# Redirect user after login issue

Tags: magento-1, redirect

I am using the `customer_login` event for my observer. I am trying to redirect my user after login.

I used below code.

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
$session->setAfterAuthUrl("/checkout/onepage/");
```

I want to redirect my account page.

Any idea why this is not working ?

Comment: If I leave : $session->setAfterAuthUrl("http://myurl/checkout/"); it works !!. If I leave like this: $session->setAfterAuthUrl("http://myurl/checkout/onepage"); I am redirected to my account. Please someone explain me why ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try below working code.

```
 public function setRedirectOnLogin(){
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer(), 'checkout') === false)
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getBaseUrl());  
        else             
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/http')->getHttpReferer());

        $session->setBeforeAuthUrl('');
    }
```

Comment: Now I am redirect to cart page .

Comment: $session->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('custom/page'));
            $session->setAfterAuthUrl(Mage::getUrl('custom/page'));  change the url as per the Route.

Comment: In my case I changed the custom/page with ''checkout/onepage'. and I am still redirected to cart

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 supports automatic redirection to the account page by default. To enable that, all you need to do is go to **System > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Login Options** and **set Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in to Yes.**

Comment: I want to redirect to a custom URL. If I set this to yes, will it work ?

Comment: @AttilaNaghi no sorry, I thought you wanted to redirect to the account page.